# Why does my custom error filter not catch all errors?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-filters

I have the following custom filter, borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18045729/8741):

```
public class JsonErrorAttribute: FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));
        }
        if (filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            var code = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult() { Data = filterContext.Exception.Message };
        }
    }
}
```

Yet when I try and post to an action marked with `[HttpGet]`, e.g.

```
[HttpGet]
[JsonError]
public JsonNetResult IndexData()
{
    var bundles = Db.PointsBundles;
    var model = new PointsBundleBundleIndexViewModel();
    model.MapItems(bundles);
    var res = (JsonNetResult)Json(model.Items, null, null, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    return res;
}
```

I get a standard HTML 404 error response. I suspect, of course, this is because the 404 detection is not an exception per se, and not caught by my handler. Is there another filter I can derive from to return a Json response 404 error, or what can I do?

Comment: you may want to check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/731913/Exception-Handling-in-MVC) regarding custom error handling in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0):

You have put `[HttpGet]` on your action, but later you are using this:

```
var res = (JsonNetResult)Json(model.Items, null, null, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
```

Try removing:

```
JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
```

Comment: Thank you, but my question is not why I am getting a 404, which I know is because of the `JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet`, but how to get a decent JSON response instead of the standard HTML response.