# Asp.net core seems to ignore the Accept:"application/xml" header for my custom formatter

Tags: asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

The API I'm building returns json almost everywhere, but I sometimes need to return xml with a custom formatter.

I created a custom formatter (I didn't copy the `WriteResponseBodyAsync` to keep it shorter)

```
public class XmlOutputFormatter : TextOutputFormatter
{
    public XmlOutputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml"));
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
    }

    protected override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true; // I tried doing this to force it to work on any type, 
                     // but I don't think it's needed
    }

    public override bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        return context.ContentType.ToString() == "application/xml";
    }
}
```

It works when I have

```
[Produces("application/xml")]
```

on a controller method, but when I don't use this and ask for xml in postman using the `Accept:application/xml` header it still returns json.

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJYHc.png)

I added the formatter in Startup.cs like so:

```
services
    .AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlOutputFormatter());
    });
```

I know the formatter works the issue is that asp seems to ignore the Accept header and always returns json. I know I could simply force it to return xml, but I would prefer returning xml.

I know there is a default xml formatter, but it doesn't behave exactly like I need it to.

I'm using asp.net core 2.0 and visual studio professional 2017 15.3 preview 6

Comment: Does it work with one of the two standard XML output formatters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a bit hasty... Hopefully it will cover enough to answer your question.

### Check your `Content-Type` and `Accept`

You need to make sure that your `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers in your request are set properly. In your case (application/xml).

I have a full example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42360418/3645638). Note that I use `AddMvcCore` (see next section below)

### Use `AddMvcCore` instead.

> The key here is to not use the default `AddMvc` method and switch to `AddMvcCore` instead for a higher degree of control of the middleware.

The reason being, is that **the order you add your options will greatly impact the way the MVC middleware will behave.** In my experience with dealing with any API using .NET Core, I avoid `AddMvc` in order to get full control over the middleware.

There really is not much to fear here, as you can see that `AddMvc` is nothing more than a template that configures the options for `AddMvcCore`. You can see the source at the repository [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs).

I've grabbed a code snippet from my related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42365276/3645638) (maybe want to take a read for a more in-depth response to how `AddMvcCore` works.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Build a customized MVC implementation, without using the default AddMvc(),
    // instead use AddMvcCore(). The repository link is below:
    // https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

    services
        .AddMvcCore(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsPermanent = true; // this does not affect api requests
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; // false by default
                                                       //options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();

            // these two are here to show you where to include custom formatters
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new CustomOutputFormatter());
            options.InputFormatters.Add(new CustomInputFormatter());
        })
        //.AddApiExplorer()
        //.AddAuthorization()
        .AddFormatterMappings()
        //.AddCacheTagHelper()
        //.AddDataAnnotations()
        //.AddCors()
        .AddJsonFormatters();
}
```

### Your Custom Formatter

Just a little bit of a nudge, but no real serious concerns, here is a cleaner implementation of your custom formatter which might get you a bit more mileage.

```
public class CustomOutputFormatter : OutputFormatter
{
    public string ContentType { get; private set; }

    public CustomOutputFormatter()
    {
        ContentType = "application/custom";
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/custom"));
    }

    protected override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        // serialize it.
        byte[] serializedBytes = ...
        response.Body.WriteAsync(serializedBytes, 0, serializedBytes.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer I read it all and it seems like the right answer I will try it out tomorrow as soon as I have access to my computer.

Comment: I tried it and it works perfectly thank you. At first I had an error because I needed the .AddApiExplorer() middleware, but I'm not sure why I'll need to do some research.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this to your Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
  options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; // false by default
}
```

Comment: I already tried that. This is not the same thing. This is to allow the default browser accept header instead of sending json everytim. This is not for custom request header.