# In an ASP.NET Core Web App, what's the difference between AddJsonOptions and AddJsonFormatters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to control *all* json output settings across the board, like for normal HTTP 200 OK results to things like when model validation fails (HTTP 400 BAD Request) etc.

I ran across these two methods in `startup.cs` :-

- `AddJsonOptions(options => ...)`
- `AddJsonFormatters(options => ...)`

Can someone please explain the difference between these two? Why I would use one over the other etc?

FWIW, I'm also trying to use Newtonsoft JSON as my json provider under the hood, with settings like this:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    Formatting = Formatting.None,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
};
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### AddJsonOptions

This provides the means to configure the serailization settings and contract resolver which have already setup by calling `.AddMvc()` on the service collection. You can see from the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L52) that `AddJsonFormatters()` is already called by `AddMvc()`. Hence, JSON.net will be used for serialization with a [DefaultContractResolver and default settings](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/JsonSerializerSettingsProvider.cs) provided. However, you can use `AddJsonOptions()` in this situation to override the defaults and specify your desired contract resolver and serializer settings e.g.

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(o => 
    {
        o.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        o.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

### AddJsonFormatters

If you are using the barebones `AddMvcCore()` on your service collection, then formatting for JSON serialization middleware will not be setup by default ([see the source on GitHub repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)). Consequently, you will need to call `AddJsonFormatters()` in order to explicitly setup and configure the resolver and serializer settings:

```
services.AddMvcCore()
    .AddJsonFormatters(o =>
    {
        o.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        o.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

### Summary

You can see that both of these methods are very similar. The only reason that they both exist is because `AddMvcCore()` allows you to setup or create your own Serialization middleware. If you like the barebones setup that `AddMvcCore()` provides but want to use the JSON serialization formatting provided by `AddMvc()` then just call `services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters()`.

For a more in-depth description of the differences between `AddMvc()` and `AddMvcCore()` see the excellent post on [What is the difference between AddMvc() and AddMvcCore()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365275/how-to-implement-a-pure-asp-net-core-web-api-by-using-addmvccore/42365276#42365276)

Comment: Perfect! Answer includes helpful points comparing the two AND links to backup claims. Thank you @calc ! For The Record: I'm using `AddMvcCore()` so I'll go with `AJF` instead of `AJO`. Cheers, again!