# How to convert String response (Text) to JSON response in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to convert String response to Json response. But I have to use different way to fix my issue but I couldn't able to find any good solution for that.

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string successResponse = "Order Created Successfully with InterfaceRecordId : " + order.WMWDATA.Receipts.Receipt.InterfaceRecordId + " & ReceiptId : " +
      order.WMWDATA.Receipts.Receipt.ReceiptId;
    _logger.LogInformation(successResponse);
    return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode, successResponse);
}
_logger.LogError(jsonResponse);
return StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode, jsonResponse);
```

I just need to send this `successRespose` as JSON response. Can you please help me to resolve this.

Comment: BTW, a string is already a valid JSON object, so what error are you having defining a `jsonReponse` string variable?

Comment: @OneCricketeer no I have checked in the Postman. It is sending text format response. So do you have any idea.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, It is not sending any errors , but response is coming as text. So i need to get json format in postman

Comment: 1) You need to return a header for `application/json` 2) You may want to try returning a Dictionary object rather than just a string if you want an object of key value pairs

Comment: You may want to read solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360139/asp-net-core-return-json-with-status-code

Comment: @OneCricketeer I need to send this (Shipment Order Created Successfully with InterfaceRecordId : 03 & ShipmentId : SHIPTESTCS020202) one as Json response.If you can send me code. Little bit hard to understand above solution. Previously I used that way. Can u please put code

Comment: That itself isn't json, though, so seems you may want to learn more about what that actually means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a read over [Format response data in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-6.0).  There are multiple possibilities, depending on what your exact requirements are.

The simplest option is to add `[Produces]` attribute to the controller action, specifying the type that's returned from the aciton:

```cs
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult YourAction(int id) { ... }
```

The above action will return `application/json` even when the return type of the action is `string`.

---

However, it looks like you're returning two values in the string (`InterfaceRecordId` and `ReceiptId`).  You can use built-in methods (such as `Ok()`, `BadRequest()`, `Created()`, `NotFound()`, etc) which convert the object to JSON and return a specific status code.

I would recommend returning an object containing both values, and use a convenience return method (`Created()` or `CreatedAtAction()`).  The following returns an anonymous object and status code 201:

```cs
var successResponse = new 
{ 
    InterfaceRecordId = order.WMWDATA.Receipts.Receipt.InterfaceRecordId,
    ReceiptId = order.WMWDATA.Receipts.Receipt.ReceiptId
}

return CreatedAtAction(nameof(YourAction), successResponse);
```

The [`CreatedAtAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.createdataction?view=aspnetcore-6.0) (and `Created`) convenience methods return a 201 (created) HTTP Code - so the client will be able to infer that from the status code.  And since it's returning an object (rather than a string), the return type defaults to `application/json`, so there's no need for the `[Produces]` attribute.