# Convert list to json in .NET Core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core

I am a beginner, I wrote a code to return data in a list, but I want data to be in json

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getproject")]
public List<ProjectModel> GetProjects()
{
    return new List<ProjectModel>()
                {
                    new ProjectModel() { Id = 1, Project_Name = "abc", Description = "1st project", Type = "plot", SA_Universe_Code = "@ff" },
                    new ProjectModel() { Id = 2, Project_Name = "def", Description = "1st project", Type = "plot", SA_Universe_Code = "@ff" }
    
                };
}
```

Comment: See the top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360139/asp-net-core-return-json-with-status-code You aren't concerned with status codes here but that's an example of returning your result as Json.

Comment: Your code already returns JSON response. The `List<ProjectModel>` is automatically serialized to JSON by the framework.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JsonResult` like:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getproject")]
public JsonResult GetProjects()
{
    var data = new List<ProjectModel>()
                {
                    new ProjectModel() { Id = 1, Project_Name = "abc", Description = "1st project", Type = "plot", SA_Universe_Code = "@ff" },
                    new ProjectModel() { Id = 2, Project_Name = "def", Description = "1st project", Type = "plot", SA_Universe_Code = "@ff" }
    
                };

    return Json(data);
}
```

Or you can use json serializer in namespace:

```
using System.Text.Json
```

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getproject")]
public IActionResult GetProjects()
{
    var data = new List<ProjectModel>()
                {
                    new ProjectModel() { Id = 1, Project_Name = "abc", Description = "1st project", Type = "plot", SA_Universe_Code = "@ff" },
                    new ProjectModel() { Id = 2, Project_Name = "def", Description = "1st project", Type = "plot", SA_Universe_Code = "@ff" }
    
                };

    var serializedData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);

    return Ok(serializedData);
}
```