# How can i return status code in JsonResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can i return json result with a status code?

Here is my get method

```
 public JsonResult<List<AspNetCompaniesClass>> Get()
 {
   List<AspNetCompaniesClass> mItems = new List<AspNetCompaniesClass>();
   return Json(mItems);
 }
```

Comment: That will return 200 OK. What do you want to return instead ? also is your code compilable ?

Comment: My code is an example, i want to create an if statement which it will return instead of 200 OK, example 400 bad request in else statement.

Comment: See this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370251/return-json-with-error-status-code-mvc

Comment: They sat to throw new exception throw new ValidationException(Json(response));, but i dont want status code 500 but 400

Comment: @Dim: The first comment on the accepted answer of the linked duplicate may be of particular interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370251/return-json-with-error-status-code-mvc#comment20726712_11443564  In the answer, specifically focus on where they set `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` and set `StatusCode` on the `Response`.  You can do this directly inside your controller action if you prefer.

Comment: Ok i found this on your link,     var errorResponse = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent,"");
            throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);. It really works, but i want to ask, is there any performace issue if i will throw new exception instead to return json result?

Comment: @Dim: Probably, but you don't *need* to throw an exception.  Just set the status code on the response before returning.

Comment: Thank you david can you give me an example?

Comment: @Dim: `Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;`

Comment: It doesnt work. do i need to place TrySkipIisCustomErrors before?