# How to return response JSON data with status code?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, razor-pages

When I used MVC controllers I used "return OK(object);" or "return BadRequest(ErrorMessage)" and such.

How can I achieve this is Razor Pages?

I tried return new JsonResult(object); which works when the status code can be 200.
But what if I want to return status code 400 with a JSON error message.

Comment: Review this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43069917/7855321)

Comment: Razor pages are more similar to WebForms. For Applications returning json MVC/WebAPI APIs are recommended

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a `JsonResult` from a Razor Page handler method, and set the HTTP status code for the response:

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 400;
    return new JsonResult(new { message = "Error" } );
}
```