# ASP .NET MVC - return Exception message to ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My ajax call:

```
  $.ajax({
     url: './Orders/SaveOrder',
     type: "POST",
     data: JSON.stringify(data),
     dataType: "JSON",
     contentType: "application/json",
     success: function (d) {
     if (d.status == true) {
          alert('Successfully saved.');
       }
       else {
             alert('Failed' + d.ErrorMessage);
        }
       },
       error: function (error) {
         alert('Error. Please try again.');
        }
```

And my SaveOrder controller action:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult SaveOrder(OrderVM o)
  {
    try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                      // do some database work
                    }
                }

                return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status} };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // how to return jsonresult with error?
            }
        }
```

How do I get the ajax request to receive the details from the try-catch catch block?  Specifically how does the 'error: function...' section get the code back?

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370251/return-json-with-error-status-code-mvc/43069917), see if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, ex.Message);
```

I believe this would work with Ajax and you can get the error message from the error parameter.  Hope it works!

edit:  For the ajax error, you can access the error message:

```
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error.statusText);
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but the method expects a Jsonresult to be returned.

Comment: Change the return type of the method to ActionResult, and you can still use JsonResult along with returning a StatusCode() for your errors.